# Get the Repository of a Target Entity from the Abstract Class in Doctrine 2.5

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Using Symfony 2.7 and Doctrine 2.5, I have

- an Interface `Alsciende\MyBundle\Model\CycleInterface`
- an abstract class `Alsciende\MyBundle\Entity\Cycle` that implements the interface
- a final class `AppBundle\Entity\Cycle` that extends the abstract class and implements the interface
- a doctrine orm configuration with `resolve_target_entities` that maps the interface to the final class

This system works well and I was able to create the database and implements some CRUD in AppBundle, manipulating the target entity directly.

However, I now want to manipulate the target entity in MyBundle, through the Interface. I need to get its repository:

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Alsciende\MyBundle\Model\CycleInterface');
```

But I get the exception

```
class 'Alsciende\MyBundle\Model\CycleInterface' does not exist
```

How can I get the repository of the target entity? That is, how can I call ResolveTargetEntityListener directly to get the name of the entity implementing the interface?

edit:

Why do I need that? Very simply, for example, I need a controller that displays a list of all Cycles. The interface defines that each Cycle has an id and a name. I want to display every Cycle with its name and id. In order to do that, I need to access the repository of the actual Cycle entities.

*Alsciende/MyBundle/Model/CycleInterface.php*

```
<?php 

namespace Alsciende\MyBundle\Model;

interface CycleInterface 
{
    public function getId();
    public function getName();
}
```

*Alsciende/MyBundle/Controller/CycleController.php*

```
<?php

namespace Alsciende\MyBundle\Controller;

class CycleController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $cycles = $this
            ->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('Alsciende\MyBundle\Model\CycleInterface')
            ->findAll();

        // return template with list $cycles
        // using only id and name properties
    }
}
```

It's the same way that FosUserBundle is able to manage the User entities, even though the User class defined in FosUserBundle is an abstract class.

Comment: Did you read about Doctrine Inheritance? http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

Comment: I did. I applied what's in that documentation.

Comment: I've read, on another SO question, that you can only query `Doctrine` by something that can be instantiated... Clearly neither `interface` nor `abstract class` cannot be. Maybe someone else could elaborate on this...

Comment: The ResolveTargetEntityListener lets us use the interface in place of the entity: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/resolve-target-entity-listener.html . The question is, how to use it in that case.

Comment: What is it exactly what you are trying to achieve? I mean, why do you need to manipualte the target entity and why do you need to get the repository? Just asking as there might be another way of achieving what you need.

Comment: I edited my question to explain what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: So did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: No. It looks like the only way to go is to define the FQCN of the concrete class in the bundle's configuration. See for example the configuration parameters fos_user.user_class, fos_oauth_server.client_class, etc.

Comment: @Alsciende - ResolveTargetEntityListener wouldn't work well AFAIK. It just maps an interface to entity during lookups. Nothing less, nothing more.

Answer (score -1):

> How can I get the repository of the target entity?

In `app/config/config.yml` put:

`doctrine:
   orm:
      resolve_target_entities:
         Namespace\InterfaceInterface: Namespace\Entity\TargetEntityImplementing`

**BUT**

> Why do I need that? Very simply, for example, I need a controller that displays a list of all Cycles. The interface defines that each Cycle has an id and a name. I want to display every Cycle with its name and id. In order to do that, I need to access the repository of the actual Cycle entities.

It's not a solution in this case, IMO. I would rather used entity with `@DiscriminatorColumn` configured:
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance

Parent class will be some kind of interface you're looking for.

I recommend you to "merge" above: create a parent class which will implement such an interface, then map this interface to this class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. @DiscriminatorColumn is not a good solution in my case. I only have one final class implementing CycleInterface. But I'm trying to manipulate this final class without knowing it yet, through its interface, like what FOSUserBundle does with UserInterface.

Comment: You cannot describe an interface. It must be an instantiable class or - if it's mapped-superclass - abstract which is extended by target entity.

Comment: My question boils down to something very simple: "how can I use ResolveTargetEntityListener directly?". Your answer doesn't appear to be really related. Either it's possible to call ResolveTargetEntityListener directly, or it's not.

Comment: I mean using ResolveTargetEntityListener to get the FQCN of the class mapped to the interface. I think I can start with what has been done here: https://github.com/Sylius/SyliusResourceBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/DoctrineTargetEntitiesResolver.php

Comment: This is exactly what I pointed you at in the first part of my answer... O.o'

Comment: I already configured the `resolve_target_entities` entry in my `config.yml`. That's the fourth bullet in my introduction. Now, I need to call the ResolveTargetEntityListener directly in my code to get the FQCN of the class mapped to the interface.

Comment: If you've configured this item, interfaces should be mapped correctly. If you want to add this from compiler-pass, make sure your bundle is being constructed BEFORE Doctrine in ``AppKernel.php``.